# What is wrong with the "GOTO" command?

Tags: batch-file, goto

```
@echo off
title Variables
set age= default
set name = defualt
set teaornah = deafault
set transport = deafault
echo How old are you, my fine friend?
set /p age=
echo So, you are %age% years old? Interesting!
pause
echo And what might your namesake be, old fellow?
set /p name=
echo Oh that's right! It's %name%! I'm am absolutly HORRID with names! Dear me!
pause
echo so, %name%, would you like to go to get some tea?
set /p teaornah=
if %teaornah% == yes goto yes
if %teaornah% == no goto no
:yes
echo very well then!
echo Would you like to take a bus or car?
set /p transport=
if transport == car goto car

if transport == bus goto bus
:car
echo we seem to be caught up in a traffic jam.
echo how awful.
echo fine weather, huh?
echo you're not very talkative.
echo goodbye.
pause
exit

:bus
echo You are victorious, %name%!
pause
exit
:no
echo Oh. How bad. I think I shall kill you now.
pause
exit
```

This is my code. I am a beginner batch user, and have just learned the goto command, yet when one types in "bus" after set /p transport=, it instead of going to :bus it goes to :car. I would like some help, as I have found similar problems with other programs. The goto :no works, as does the goto :yes, but no other goto works. Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

what's the difference between these two sets of lines?

```
if %teaornah% == yes goto yes
if %teaornah% == no goto no

if transport == car goto car
if transport == bus goto bus
```

In reality, neither of those last two lines go anywhere. Your code checks if the word `transport` equals the word `car` and decides it does not, so it continues to the next line. Then it checks if the word `transport` equals the word `bus` and decides it does not, so it continues to the next line which is the start of the `car` label.

Some other thoughts about your code:

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to `var`.

`if /i "%var%"=="value"` performs a comparison on variables/values containing separators (eg spaces) The '/i' make the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: Certainly. OP should also be aware that `set` is space-ensitive, so `set name = defualt` will set a variable called "name " not "name". Also the syntax `if /i "%var%"=="value"` is preferrred since the quotes defuse variables whose values contain separators like spaces. the `/i` makes the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: @Magoo just headed out the door from work, but that's answer material (even if it doesn't answer the question as asked). Could you edit some of that copy into my answer?